# Load views with AngularJS and Django

Tags: angularjs, django

I'm trying to swap views when I click a link using AngularJS.

My index.html is something like that:

```
<head>
  <script src="media/static/js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="media/static/js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="media/static/js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="media/static/js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
  <a href="#view1">View1</a>
  <a href="#view2">View2</a>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

My app.js is something like that:

```
angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']).

config(['$routeProvider', function( $routeProvider) {

  // Define routes 
   $routeProvider
     .when('/view1', 
           { templateUrl: 'templates/view1.html'})
     .when('/view2',
           { templateUrl: 'templates/view2.html'})
     .otherwise({redirectTo: 'view1'});
 }]);
```

I'm completely new with Angular and I'm going crazy trying that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime ago, I wrote a snnipet for this, you can found it [here](https://gist.github.com/Gocht/31cc901dbb6fcffa7913). Please give a feedback if it's useful and is still working.